# Sikuli List of Functions & Operators

Tags: python, list, function, sikuli, operations

I've just discovered [Sikuli](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/uid/sikuli/index.shtml), and would like to see a comprehensive functions list without digging through the online-examples and demos.

Has anyone found such a list?

Furthermore, apparently Sikuli supports more complex loops and function calls as well, and seems to be based in Python(!!). Examples would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the docs can be found at [the sikuli home page](http://doc.sikuli.org/).

Comment: The homepage is full of lots of things, but it's never obvious to me where the "comprehensive functions list" is located in that mess.

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing you were looking for this page:

[The General API Index](http://doc.sikuli.org/genindex.html)

It took me a while to find it when I was first looking into Sikuli.  It explains the API of the classes and functions included with Sikuli.  Its the next place to go after looking over a few Hello World-style examples.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent, you found the docs.  Have you checked their launchpad project for code  examples?  If not, sign up  https://launchpad.net/sikuli  Questions can be asked and answers given.   There are lots of good code examples as well.  Beware of the idiotic drivel posted by Surfdork.
Oops, that's me.
I have answers for questions beyond Sikuli such as the architecture needed to use Sikuli as an enterprise level testing tool, image managment, variable managment, configuring an IDE to use Sikuli etc.

Cheers!

Surfdork

Answer (score 0):

Sikuli seems to have moved from the MIT website to http://www.sikuli.org where the links to demos and documentation actually do work.